# PHP creating RSS-feed, not updating

Tags: php, mysql, rss, feed

I have created a simple **RSS-feed with PHP**, which gets the latest news (20 items) from my MySQL-db.

When I run this in Mozilla Firefox, everything works great without an issue. When there is a 'new post', I can update and the new post will be shown. But when I run the same on my iPhone via (Simple RSS app) it does not work. It seems like it is updated, and remains updated, by the time I first read it in the 20 items.

I have tried to set `no-cache`, and to send header information that the page was last modified, as the page is loaded. But it's not working.

Many thanks for some inputs! I have struggled with this for two weeks now with a lot of googling.

Best Regards,
Dasman

Answer (score 0):

To make your RSS-feed to work on iPhone via Simple RSS app, try Creating an RSS feed that:

1. Conforms to the **RSS 2.0 specification**
2. Includes the [recommended iTunes RSS](https://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#rss) tags